# Python JWT and RSA

Tags: python, rsa, pyjwt

I would like to learn about creating JWT using RSA public and private key. I am a beginner to learn securing my services. I am using pyjwt right now. I got something error with my testing, here it is:

SAMPLEKEY:

```
privatekey = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"""

publickey = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCkC2AfenNMfrU4oMfMZt9aZGBbFjzBTjV9Yttp0GHeVjIKboTwLkiKNqSKrm2Jralbteii2J9h6BeUBpv3B/Os7M0eNeM8B+5Rzm44vcmkzdtufTuX2utjoz8BFjelXw5og2i67NtxgiSHv2x1KCHbGZG+jpDOgjorxFusKbeGjQIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""
```

Here is my sample code:

```
@app.route('/token')
def token():
    encodedToken = jwt.encode({'userid':'1'}, publickey, algorithm = 'RS256')
    print(jwt.decode(encodedToken, privatekey, verify=True, algorithms='RS256'))
    return "OKE"
```

And, I am getting this error when running it:

[image]

Is there any solution into this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Basically you'll want to switch the keys, use the private key for "encoding" (signing) and public for "decoding" (verification).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is reported on GitHub here: https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/issues/81

And marked as "closed".